# boost logging severity level filter not honored

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

This is driving me nuts. I am setting the severity level explicitly but boost.log does not honour it. All messages with all severity levels are logged.

here is the code I am using:

the is_verbose flag obviously obtained from command line. And a message logged via:

```
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "Hello there!" ;
```

will be logged and shown on terminal.

Thanks.

```
#include "boost/log/core.hpp"
#include "boost/log/expressions.hpp"
#include "boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp"
#include "boost/log/trivial.hpp"
#include "boost/log/attributes.hpp"
#include "boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp"

#include "Logger.h"

namespace logging = boost::log;

void Logger::init(bool is_verbose) {

    if(is_verbose)
        logging::core::get()->set_filter(
            logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info);
    else
        logging::core::get()->set_filter(
            logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::error);   

    namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
    namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;

    logging::add_file_log(
            keywords::auto_flush = true,
            keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
            keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
            keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
            keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%][%Severity%]: %Message%"
            );

    logging::add_common_attributes();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/897aa887e09095e8)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;

struct Logger {
    void init(bool is_verbose) {
        namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
        namespace sinks    = boost::log::sinks;
        namespace trivial  = boost::log::trivial;

        if(!is_verbose)
            logging::core::get()->set_filter(trivial::severity >= trivial::warning);   

        logging::add_file_log(
                keywords::auto_flush          = true,
                keywords::file_name           = is_verbose? "verbose_%N.log":"sample_%N.log",
                keywords::rotation_size       = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
                keywords::format              = "[%TimeStamp%][%Severity%]: %Message%"
            );

        logging::add_common_attributes();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char**) {
    Logger logger;
    logger.init(argc>1);

    {
        using sl = boost::log::trivial::severity_level;
        logging::sources::severity_logger<sl> lg;

        BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, sl::trace) << "trace";
        BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, sl::fatal) << "fatal";
    }

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "trivial trace";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "trivial fatal";
}
```

Testing:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Os -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp \
      -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup
./a.out
./a.out -v
tail *.log
```

Prints

```
==> sample_0.log <==
[2015-Sep-02 09:49:22.172371][]: fatal
[2015-Sep-02 09:49:22.174915][]: trivial fatal

==> verbose_0.log <==
[2015-Sep-02 09:49:22.226536][]: trace
[2015-Sep-02 09:49:22.227292][]: fatal
[2015-Sep-02 09:49:22.227380][]: trivial trace
[2015-Sep-02 09:49:22.227408][]: trivial fatal
```

Comment: hello @sehe is boost.logging affected by some sort of env variable or anything like that? I copied your code into a file, compiled it with your command above and ran same commands you did. nothing showed up in either case. No trace level, not even fatal level messages. Absolutely nothing. And in my project I still see messages not matter if I chose verbose mode or not. It has a mind of its own.

Comment: You should probably start eliminating (removing/commenting) code until you see the behaviour change. Focus on the initialization code.